# Render sub arrays with http client manger API calls response

Tags: 8, http-request

I am trying to consume [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#namedapiresource) using Drupal. For making API calls I am using [HTTP Client Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client_manager) module. I am able to set up initial configuration and get the data when the response field is a string. But I am not able to get data when the response field is array.Can any one please point out what I am doing wrong.

I am just trying to make a HttpGet  request to the following URL

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=300&limit=100

As the API has documentation of their resource Documentation I felt it would be good until I hit the wall of dealing with Array field. If anyone got suggestion for better approach I would like to try it out.

My code is as follows :

**pokeapi/pokeapi.http_services_api.yml**

```
pokeapi.base:
  title: "Drupal and PokeAPI Services API"
  api_path: "src/api/pokeapi_services.yml"
  config:
    base_uri: "https://pokeapi.co/"
    debug: "/tmp/pokeapi.log"
```

**pokeapi/src/api/pokeapi_services.yml**

```
name: "Drupal and PokeAPI Services API"
apiVersion: "2.0"
description: "Drupal Client wrapper for the PokeAPI Services API."
imports:
  - "resources/posts.yml"
  # - "resources/models.yml"
```

**pokeapi/src/api/resources/posts.yml**

```
operations:
  GetPokemonsList:
    httpMethod: "GET"
    uri: "/api/v2/pokemon?limit={limit}&offset={offset}"
    summary: "Gets the available Pokemons List. It's possible to define a limit and offset."
    parameters:
      limit:
        location: "query"
        description: "The number of Pokemons data to be retrieved."
        type: "integer"
        required: true
        default: 100
      offset:
        location: "query"
        description: "The offset."
        type: "integer"
        required: true
        default: 200
    responseModel: "PokemonsList"

models:
  PokemonsList:
    type: "array"
    location: "json"
    items:
      "$ref": "NamedAPIResourceList"

  NamedAPIResourceList:
    type: "object"
    location: "json"
    properties:
      count:
        location: "json"
        type: "integer"
      next:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      previous:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      results:
        location: "json"
        type: "array"
        items:
          "$ref": "DetailedResourceList"

  DetailedResourceList:
    type: "array"
    location: "json"
    properties:
      name:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      url:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
```

**pokeapi/src/Controller/PokeAPIController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pokeapi\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\http_client_manager\HttpClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Returns responses for PokeAPI routes.
 */
class PokeAPIController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * PokeAPI Http Client.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\http_client_manager\HttpClientInterface
   */
  protected $httpClient;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $http_client) {
    $this->httpClient = $http_client;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('pokeapi.http_client')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Get Client.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\http_client_manager\HttpClientInterface
   *   The Http Client instance.
   */
  public function getClient() {
    return $this->httpClient;
  }

  /**
   * Builds the response.
   */
  public function build() {

    $client = $this->getClient();
    $command = 'GetPokemonsList';

    $response = $client->call($command)->toArray();
    dpm($response);

    $build['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('It works!'),
    ];

    return $build;
  }

}
```

result of dpm($response);

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1118
    [1] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=300&limit=100
    [2] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=100&limit=100
    [3] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

here array value indexed 3 in response should contain result array of the data.

I believe there is some error in the following definition in the `posts.yml` If anyone can point out the correct way it will be helpful.

> ```
>       results:
>         location: "json"
>         type: "array"
>         items:
>           "$ref": "DetailedResourceList"
>
>   DetailedResourceList:
> ```

Similar Question : [How can I access nested data?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300460/how-can-i-access-nested-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake in models structure, use below one will solve your issue

```
models:
  PokemonsList:
    type: "object"
    location: "json"
    properties:
      count:
        location: "json"
        type: "integer"
      next:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      previous:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      results:
        type: "array"
        location: "json"
        items:
          "$ref": "DetailedResourceList"

  DetailedResourceList:
    type: "object"
    location: "json"
    properties:
      name:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
      url:
        location: "json"
        type: "string"
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.